# iText - check if attachment exists / link attachment multiple times

Tags: java, itext

Is there a way to check if an attachment is already present in the PDF document while creating the document (not after the document is saved to disk)? While parsing a XML to PDF I came across over multiple attachments which have the same content (Base64 String from XML > byte[]) and the same name. Currently the attachments are added multiple times, but I want to check if an attachment (with the same content or name) already exists (PdfWriter API?) and if YES, only a new Annotation should be created to the existing attachment.

**NOTE:** the check should happen while creating the PDF, not with a PdfReader and an existing PDF

**EDIT:**
Thanks to @Bruno Lowagie I got it working:

```
protected HashMap<String, PdfFileSpecification> cache = new HashMap<>();
private final byte[] BUFFER = new byte[1024];

public PdfFileSpecification getPdfFileSpecification(final PdfWriter pdfWriter, final String name, final byte[] data) throws IOException {

    String hash = createMD5Hash(data);
    PdfFileSpecification pdfFileSpecification = cache.get(hash);

    if (pdfFileSpecification == null) {
        pdfFileSpecification = PdfFileSpecification.fileEmbedded(pdfWriter, null, name, data);
        cache.put(hash, pdfFileSpecification);
        return pdfFileSpecification;
    }
    System.out.println(String.format("Name: %s Hash: %s", name, hash));
    return pdfFileSpecification;
}

private String createMD5Hash(final byte[] data) {

MessageDigest messageDigest;

    try {
        messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        return null;
    }

    ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);

    try {
        int i;
        while ((i = byteArrayInputStream.read(BUFFER)) != -1) {
            messageDigest.update(BUFFER, 0, i);
        }
        byteArrayInputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
    byte[] mdbytes = messageDigest.digest();

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < mdbytes.length; i++) {
        sb.append(Integer.toString((mdbytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

So every time I have to deal with a new attachment I do it like this:

```
PdfFileSpecification fs = getPdfFileSpecification(pdfWriter, name, data)
PdfAnnotation an = PdfAnnotation.createFileAttachment(pdfWriter, rectangle, name, fs);
```

Comment: Define "while parsing an XML to PDF". How are you creating the PDF based on the XML you're parsing? Introduce a caching system into that process and if an attachment is in the cache, then it shouldn't be added anew. This is not something iText will deal with, this is something that needs to be dealt with in the software that uses iText.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie like "loading a xml into the memory, creating an in-memory PdfWriter (which writes to a BAOS) adding Paragraphes and attachments with text and Base64 encoded data from the XML by querying the XML with XPath and DOM Parser and if every text node and attachment of the XML is saved to the PdfWriter finally write the BAOS to a file" hope I described it well^^

Comment: OK, so you can create a `Set` that contains hashes of the Base64 encoded data. Before you add the decoded data to the PDF, hash the Base64 data, check if it's already present in the `Set`. If so, don't add the attachment. If not, put the hash in the `Set` and add the attachment. Why would you need iText to do that?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie you are right, sorry I dont have the practise for such things so I havent thought of this :)

Comment: No need to say sorry for asking a question ;-)

Comment: @BrunoLowagie okay after I checked if the attachment already exists, how can I set a reference to it? see Edit on how far I am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow me to take your code and introduce some pseudo code to show you how I would do this:

```
protected Map<String, PdfFileSpecification> cache =
    new HashMap<String, PdfFileSpecification>();

public void cellLayout(final PdfPCell pdfPCell, final Rectangle rectangle, final PdfContentByte[] pdfContentBytes) {
    String hasheddata = createHash(attachment);
    PdfFileSpecification fs = cache.get(hasheddata);
    if (fs == null) {
        fs = PdfFileSpecification.fileEmbedded(writer, null, displayname, attachment);
        cache.put(hasheddata, fs);
    }
    PdfAnnotation an = PdfAnnotation.createFileAttachment(writer, rectangle, displayname, fs);
    writer.addAnnotation(an);
}
```

This code won't compile because I left out some parts that aren't relevant to the problem. I only kept the stuff that explains the concept of creating the cache for the file specifications.

I create a hash of the `attachment` bytes to save memory. You will have to implement the `createHash()` method using the hashing algorithm of your choice. Before I create a new `FileSpecification` that will write bytes to the `PdfWriter`, I check if I can't reuse an already existing file specification. If one exists, I reuse it in an annotation. If it doesn't exist I create a new file specification.

Comment: Hell Yeah this is exactly I was looking for! Thank you so much for your affort and time to help me! If you know a way how I can donate you a coffee, tell me!